# GDB breakpoint when executing external program through system()

Tags: c, gdb

I have the function `system()` call a separate script that has already been compiled. But I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint in functions within THAT specific file.

So:

File A:

```
system("./fileB");
```

File B:

```
void main() {
 /* etc */
}
```

I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint at main after the system command is called.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of GDB ([7.1+](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/MultiProcess)) can [debug multiple programs at once](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html) and can indeed support this:

**run-program.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("./program-i-want-to-debug");
    return 0;
}
```

**program-i-want-to-debug.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**run-program.gdb**

```
set detach-on-fork off
set target-async on
set pagination off
set non-stop on

add-inferior -exec program-i-want-to-debug
break program-i-want-to-debug.c:5
file run-program
run

inferior 3
backtrace
```

Sample session

```
$ gdb -q -x run-program.gdb
Added inferior 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400441: file program-i-want-to-debug.c, line 5.
[New process 20297]
process 20297 is executing new program: /usr/bin/bash
process 20297 is executing new program: /home/scottt/Dropbox/stackoverflow/program-i-want-to-debug
Reading symbols from /home/scottt/Dropbox/stackoverflow/program-i-want-to-debug...done.

Breakpoint 1, main () at program-i-want-to-debug.c:5
5       printf("Hello, World\n");
[Switching to inferior 3 [process 20297] (/home/scottt/Dropbox/stackoverflow/program-i-want-to-debug)]
[Switching to thread 2 (process 20297)] 
#0  main () at program-i-want-to-debug.c:5
5       printf("Hello, World\n");
#0  main () at program-i-want-to-debug.c:5
```

Obviously you'd want to compile the programs with debug info (**gcc -g**).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not catch your point. It seems that starting gdb debug on File A and setting a breakpoint on "FileB:line of main"  resolve your problem.